# EF 6 code-first migrations skipped

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a entity framework 6 code-first project.  I deleted my database and want to re-create it from scratch.  When I run update-database some of the migrations do not run.  That causes an error later because the database is not in the expected state.

This is the first migration that is skipped:

> ```
> using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
>
> public partial class add_ConversationEntry_Type : DbMigration
> {
>     public override void Up()
>     {
>         AddColumn("dbo.ConversationEntry", "Type", c => c.String(nullable: false));
>     }
>
>     public override void Down()
>     {
>         DropColumn("dbo.ConversationEntry", "Type");
>     }
> }
> ```

It looks standard.  It inherits from DbMigration and does nothing weird.  The next 3 also are skipped and they all affect that dbo.ConversationEntry table.

With *update-datebase -verbose* it shows 'Applying explicit migrations:' and lists the migrations and these are missing from that list.

I have verified that these are also in the project file.
Where does update-database get the list of migrations?
Why would some be skipped?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Our very first migration is being skipped also...

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do in this scenario is to create an idempotent script of all the migrations and see what Entity Framework is trying to do:

```
update-database –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase -Script
```

This should have everything needed to create the database, the __MigrationHistory table and to consecutively apply your migrations.

If all other databases you care about are up to date, you could simply reset the migrations. Yet another option would be to switch the initializer to [createdatabaseifnotexists](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) which would create a new database based on your model.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
In my case we have renamed an existing migration and forgot to synchronize the two partial class names in the [Timestamp]_Migration.cs and [Timestamp]_Migration.Designer.cs files.
This didnt show any error/warning message during compilation or execution, other than the migration not being listed in the 'Applying explicit migrations' message and therefore never being applied.

Answer (score -1):

Each entity framework migration consists from three files

- entity class `.cs`

and additional code-behind files

- metadata file `.Designer.cs`
- database model snapshot `.resx`

Make sure `<timestamp>_dd_ConversationEntry_Type.Designer.cs` file is not missing and is included in your project.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score -1):

easy easy

Make sure the build action is "Compile" and don't forget to mark this answer as "Correct Answer".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj1na.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).